# What does `%.%` <- paste0 mean in R?

Tags: r

I am looking over some code from a published paper and in the preamble of their data analysis, the have the lines:

```
'%.%' <- paste0
```

and

```
d <- d2; rm(d2)
```

Thanks!

The paper in question is Zhao et. al. 2022 in the APSR

Comment: `paste0` concatenates all the string elements it receives with no spaces between. (Whereas `paste` has a default separator of a space.) They are making up an alias shortcut, presumably to save a few characters, but it seems to me like that would tend to reduce readability more than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they just created an operador to do de function work - after calling theire line execute this to see it working:

```
'%.%' <- paste0 # code in question
"abc" %.% "cde"
[1] "abccde"
```

as for the second part: the semicolon ";" can be considered a line break:

```
print(1) print(2) # throws an error
print(1); print(2)
[1] 1
[1] 2
```